# How to enable JupyterLab extension manager by default?

Tags: dockerfile, jupyter-lab

I am deploying a JupyterLab environment in Docker, to save my preferred working environment. One of the customizations is that I have an extension `jupyterlab-onedarkpro` installed. This offers the JupyterLab web app a new theme.

### Problem

However, in the Dockerfile, as I built the image by using the following codes, I still need to

1. open the JupyterLab web app,
2. manually enable the extensions from extension manager,
3. search for `jupyterlab-onedarkpro` in extension manager,
4. install it (which should be done by the bash script but seems actually not)
5. click `rebuild` as the web app suggests.

```sh
# In Dockerfile
# <jupyter> is the conda env where I installed the jupyterlab only.
RUN conda run -n jupyter /bin/bash extensions.sh

# In extensions.sh
conda install -c conda-forge -y nodejs

jupyter labextension install -y \
    @jupyterlab/application \
    @jupyterlab/apputils \
    @jupyterlab/console \
    @jupyterlab/coreutils \
    @jupyterlab/docmanager \
    @jupyterlab/filebrowser \
    @jupyterlab/mainmenu \
    @jupyterlab/notebook \
    @jupyterlab/rendermime \
    @jupyterlab/rendermime-interfaces \
    react \
    react-dom \
    @jupyterlab/debugger \
    @jupyterlab/toc \
    jupyterlab-spreadsheet \
    jupyterlab_voyager \
    @mflevine/jupyterlab_html \
    jupyterlab_onedarkpro

conda install -c conda-forge -y \
    jupyterlab-drawio \
    jupyterlab_execute_time \
    ipympl \
    plotly \
    jupyter-dash

pip install \
    jupyterlab-system-monitor \
    jupyterlab_latex

jupyter server extension disable nbclassic
npm run build
jupyter lab build
```

### Question

How can I set the `jupyterlab-onedarkpro` extension to be enabled and the JupyterLab to be rebuilt in Dockerfile ?

Comment: If this extension does not get installed it means that your bash script silently errors at some step. It's likely that build fails because you are installing core extensions as if those were third-party extensions (such as `@jupyterlab/application` or `@jupyterlab/debugger` - don't do that!)

Comment: @krassowski Sorry for reply so late. Thank you for your suggestions. However, since I found a way to use Jupyter Notebook on VS Code, I turned to that and this did simplified my efforts in adjusting editor ENVs.